# Getting Error in Login using webservice

Tags: android, json

Android code is here

```
public class NewLogin  extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText editTextUserName;
    private EditText editTextPassword;

    public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

    String username;
    String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    }

    public void invokeLogin(View view){
        username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        login(username,password);

    }

    private void login(final String username, String password) {

        class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            private Dialog loadingDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NewLogin.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String uname = params[0];
                String pass = params[1];

                InputStream is = null;
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myusername", uname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mypassword", pass));
                String result = null;

                try{
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "www.sample.com/home_webservice.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    is = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                String s = result.trim();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(NewLogin.this, Sample.class);
                  /*  intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                    finish();*/
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
        la.execute(username, password);

    }

/*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }*/
}
```

JSON CODE IS HERE

```
<?php
require '../db_connect.php';
if (isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password']))
{
    $myusername = $_GET['username'];
    $mypassword = $_GET['password']; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_registration WHERE (username = '$myusername' or email = '$myusername' or phone = '$myusername')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

    $response["VerifiedMember"] = array();
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $VerifiedMember = array();
        $id=$row['id'];
        $phone=$row['phone'];
        $reg_type=$row['register_type'];
        $stored_salt = $row['salt'];
        $stored_hash = $row['hashed_password'];
        $check_pass = $stored_salt . $mypassword;
        $check_hash = hash('sha512',$check_pass);

        if($check_hash == $stored_hash){

            $VerifiedMember['user_id'] = $id;
            $VerifiedMember['first_name']=$row['first_name'];
            $VerifiedMember['phone']=$row['phone'];
            array_push($response["VerifiedMember"], $VerifiedMember);

         if(!empty($phone)&& $reg_type==1){

             $sql="select * from user_otps where user_id='".$id."'";
             $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
             if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                if($row['verified']==0)
                {
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "failure";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);

                }
                else
                {   
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 1;
                      $response["message"] = "success";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
             }
         }
         else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 1;
                      $response["message"] = "success";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
         }
         //echo json_encode($response);
        }

        else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "invalid";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "invalid";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
?>
```

Here i m getting Invalid username and password please help me to get users details from json file in android 
how to solve this can anyone tell me ??
Here i m getting Invalid username and password please help me to get users details from json file in android 
how to solve this can anyone tell me ??

Comment: Your API is a GET request, but you are creating a POST request in from android. Also the keys you are passing to the php script, are wrong. Your MySQL query doesn't make any sense too.

Comment: help me how to create GET request using same php file @KNeerajLal

Comment: `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated. Have a look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Simply You try,**

```
public class NewLogin  extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText editTextUserName;
private EditText editTextPassword;

public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

String username;
String password;
String result;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);

    editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
}

public void invokeLogin(View view){
    new loginAccess().execute();
}


class loginAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String access;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        String url = "http://uat.ziplife.in/mobileapp/login_webservice.php";
        JSONObject json = null;

        try {
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myusername", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mypassword", password));
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);
            Log.d("TESS :: ", json.toString());
            String status = json.getString("sucess");
            Log.d("Success Response :: ", status);


            if (status.equals("success")) {


                    Intent i = new Intent(NewLogin.this, Sample.class);
                    startActivity(i);

            }
        else    if(json.getString("status").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("failed"))
            {


                Toast.makeText(NewLogin.this, "Please enter the correct details!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block flag=1;

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }



    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();



    }
}
```

Comment: sir can u edit this code in my android code  bcoz i m new in this area pls help me @Harisudhan.A

Comment: You just replace the doInBackground() from your code to my code. it will work fine.

Comment: you have add one more java file to your code, that is JsonParser.java https://codeshare.io/argKK6

Comment: parms(0) getting error in  this line 
array type excepted < NameValuePair> @Harisudhan.A

Comment: could you please share me your current code and error

Comment: String uname = params[0];
         String pass = params[1]; Array type expected;found:'java.util.List<org.apache.http.NameValuePair>  @Harisudhan.A

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at LoginAsync.onPostExecute(NewLogin.java:154)
                                                                                     at LoginAsync.onPostExecute(NewLogin.java:72)

now i m getting this error in log file @Harisudhan.A

Comment: Nothing get anything from json in log file @Harisudhan.A

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
Getting this error in LOG file

Comment: username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
Method must be called in UI thread getting this error in above line code @Harisudhan.A

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <?php
require '../db_connect.php';
if (isset($_POST['myusername']) && isset($_POST['mypassword']))
{
    $myusername = $_POST['myusername']; \\ change 
    $mypassword = $_POST['mypassword']; \\ change
```

Edit your 2 line

Comment: But in database the column name is username and password only not myusername and mypassword @AanalSaha

Comment: yes but this is not your column name in $_GET['your key'] not column name @karan brahmaxatriya

Comment: bt if i m not notupdate login php file there is any other way  to get username n password? @AanalShah

Comment: yes change this line  `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));`

Comment: still getting same error invalid username and password @AanalShah

Comment: can you give user login credential for test ?

Comment: username and  password for testing

Comment: username = kbrahmaxatriya@gmail.com
password = qwerty @AanalShah

Comment: username  = 9426473664  and password = qwerty @Aanal Shah